# iOS: The written accent in the first character doesn't appear in an UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to show a `UILabel` with a written accent in the first character but it doesn't appear.

Here is a brief explanation:

I have an `UIView` (in a xib file) which has a title and I align the text vertically with a constraint. 
I have tried to add the text with the accent mark (á, é ,í, ó, ú) programatically and with Xcode, but without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a bug in xcode. If you don't set a height constraint, the UILabel's height is adjusted automatically. That doesn't happen when the UILabel has an accent mark and it doesn't appear.

I have solved my problem adding a height constraint a little bit higher than current one.